# Application Error while opening Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio

I Have installed Microsoft Visual studio 2010 ultimate in my laptop. On trying to open the application, i am getting the below error. I have already installed VS2010 SP1. Kindly advise.

error screenshot : [image: error screenshot]

Comment: Its asking you to update to latest version.Some of the packages are updated so in-order to install, you need to update all the packages itseems.

Comment: I tried updating the whole service pack still no changes

Comment: Uninstall everything and try again know.. Make sure that the services are also deleted if any.